# how to recognize a list of number separated by blank in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I want to write a list of data to dataframe
like below:

0  19235  30307  38841  45887  51820  56950  61594  65825  69740  73216  76373  79239  81931  84439
86681  88772  90699  92422  93902  95440  96584  98084  99337  99995 101453 102611 103994 104337 105286
106379 107114 108449 109595 110379 110531 111433 111734 112757 113638 114729 115893 116951 117173 118074
118837 119885 120853 120963 120963 121619 122678 123612 124287 125011 125913 126737 127150 127411 128313
129148 129798 129798 129798 129798 130885 131583 132253 132886 133214 133916 134629 134850 135056 135492
136019 136454 136906 137267 137563 137783 137951 138144 138256 138379 138480 138552 138601 138629 138663
138674 138686 138686 138686 138686 138686 138686 138686 138686 138686

but it takes too much time to add a comma --> data.frame(x=c(1,2,3))

Is there any method that can recognize the blank and separate the numbers automatically?

Comment: Use the `scan()` function.

Comment: `data.frame(bits = unlist(strsplit('0 19235 30307 38841 etc', split = ' ')))` , if required, convert to number with `as.numeric`

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent addon called `hrbraddins` with `bare combine` or `bare space combine` availabe here https://github.com/hrbrmstr/hrbraddins

which is very helpful in such cases:
Just mark your numbers then push `bare space combine` via the addon button. Note you have to install before using:

```
c("0", "19235", "30307", "38841", "45887", "51820", "56950", "61594", "65825", "69740", "73216", "76373", "79239", "81931", "84439", "86681", "88772", "90699", "92422", "93902", "95440", "96584", "98084", "99337", "99995", "101453", "102611", "103994", "104337", "105286", "106379", "107114", "108449", "109595", "110379", "110531", "111433", "111734", "112757", "113638", "114729", "115893", "116951", "117173", "118074", "118837", "119885", "120853", "120963", "120963", "121619", "122678", "123612", "124287", "125011", "125913", "126737", "127150", "127411", "128313", "129148", "129798", "129798", "129798", "129798", "130885", "131583", "132253", "132886", "133214", "133916", "134629", "134850", "135056", "135492", "136019", "136454", "136906", "137267", "137563", "137783", "137951", "138144", "138256", "138379", "138480", "138552", "138601", "138629", "138663", "138674", "138686", "138686", "138686", "138686", "138686", "138686", "138686", "138686", "138686")
```